# How do you edit pull requests made by another user on your own repo but keep the PR active?

Tags: git, github

Lets suppose I own my own repo - lets call it `https://github.com/me/myrepo`

Now let's suppose another user forked my repo and made some edits and has submitted a PR for me to merge. Lets call his pull request `https://github.com/me/myrepo/pull/44`

1. I want to be able to clone the PR, review it, make changes
2. I want to commit these changes to the same PR
3. At a later time, I want to merge it.

So basically, given he has made a PR on *my* repo, I assume I have the right to co-commit in his PR.

The "Cli instructions" GitHub gives tells me to check out his fork via pull, make edits and then merge to master. I don't want to merge to master. I want to keep the changes in the PR, and not in his fork, but in my repo.

Can I ?

Thanks

Comment: You can check out the other user's branch, make changes, push to YOUR repo, and then create a pull request against the original author's PR (which he/she can merge to their open PR)

Answer (score 1):

In github, there is an option at creating RP to give to maintainers of the original repository permission to push to the source branch. Ask the contributor to enable it. Otherwise you can only push to another branch in your repository and suggest the fixes in comments, or create another RP.

Comment: Okay thanks. So it looks like there is no way for me to add commits to a PR on my repo in that PR branch. I either make a new branch in my repo with his PR and mine as a new PR, or I commit to his fork and ask him to merge my changes then merge to my repo.